# Making a Maven Plugin Optional?

Tags: apache, maven

How do I make a maven plugin optional so if someone does not have it, their build will not fail?  In this example, I am trying to make JSHint optional so it runs if you have access to the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a [build profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) in your project's [POM](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Profiles) and activate it according to file existence:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>jshint</id>

      <activation>
        <file>
          <exists>${user.home}/.m2/repository/path/to/jshint/artifact.jar</exists>
        </file>
      </activation>

      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            ...
          <plugin>
        <plugins>
      <build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

A limitation, however, is that the repository path contains the version.

Version-independent you could activate the profile by default in your [`settings.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Active_Profiles):

```
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>jshint</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
```

and others can activate it on the command line in case:

```
mvn ... -P jshint ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create different profiles with unique ids

```
   <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>no-optional-plugins</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <!-- active this profile to enable the docker-maven-plugin -->
    <id>docker</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.26.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <name>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.parent.artifactId}/${project.artifactId}</name>
                            <build>
                                <from>java:8-jdk-alpine</from>
                                <entryPoint>
                                    <exec>
                                        <args>java</args>
                                        <args>-jar</args>
                                        <args>/maven/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</args>
                                    </exec>
                                </entryPoint>
                                <assembly>
                                    <descriptorRef>artifact</descriptorRef>
                                </assembly>
                            </build>
                        </image>
                    </images>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Build with docker image creation **mvn clean install -P docker**

Build without docker **mvn clean install**